# What is the use of path for socket.io, how is that different from custom namespace

Tags: javascript, socket.io

```
const socket = io('http://myserver/admin', {
  path: '/mypath'
});
```

[socket.io doc](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/) said with that code the socket connects to the **admin** namespace, with the **custom path** mypath. But what the use of path here? Can't namespace alone do the job?

Or under what circumstance do I need to set custom path?